# Extracting opening hours of geocoded businesses from Google search

Tags: r, google-maps

I have a list of 1800 businesses with lat and long coordinates. I am wanting to extract the opening hours for each of these businesses from the information stored by Google Maps. Is there an easy way to use my data to retrieve this information?

[image]

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/details#PlaceOpeningHours):

PlaceOpeningHours
An object describing the opening hours of a place.

```
Field   Required    Type    Description
open_now    required    boolean
```

A boolean value indicating if the place is open at the current time.

```
periods optional    Array<PlaceOpeningHoursPeriod>
```

An array of opening periods covering seven days, starting from Sunday, in chronological order.

See PlaceOpeningHoursPeriod for more information.

```
weekday_text    optional    Array<string>
```

A boolean value indicating if the place is open at the current time.